# Editable Webix Data Table Column Headers

Tags: javascript, html, webix

Is it possible to make editable column headers in a webix data table? This code will allow for editing the data in the table but not the headers themselves:

```
 webix.ui({
    view:"datatable",
    editable:true,
    columns:[
       { id:"title",   header:"Test", fillspace:true, editor:"text"}],
    data:[
        {title:"random"}
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in solution, but it is quite easy to add an external editor

http://webix.com/snippet/379ee39b

You can create a separate popup with text editor inside

```
webix.ui({ id:"editor", view:"popup", body:{
  view:"form",
  elements:[
    { view:"text", name:"header" },
    { view:"button", value:"Save", click:function(){
      var top = this.getTopParentView();
      top.config.callback( top.getBody().getValues().header);
      top.hide();
    }}
  ]
}});
```

And later, use it from header click event

```
  onHeaderClick:function(id, ev){
    var grid = this;

    $$("editor").getBody().setValues({
        header: this.getColumnConfig(id.column).header[0].text
    });
    $$("editor").config.callback = function(value){
      grid.getColumnConfig(id.column).header[0].text = value;
      grid.refreshColumns();
    };
    $$("editor").show(ev);
    $$("editor").getBody().focus();
  }
```